# Increase number of stack frames collected by app verifier on every heap allocation

Tags: c++, winapi, windbg, stack-trace, application-verifier

I try to get a stack trace of an memory allocation by using windbg command:

```
!heap -p -a <allocation address>
```

The stack trace is collected by configuring my application to run with app verifier.

I get a stack trace but it is too short.

Is there a way to increase number of stack frames collected by app verifier ?

Thanks.

Comment: There is config for that, might have something to do with it.  Gflags.exe, Image File tab, Stack Backtrace setting.

Comment: @HansPassant that setting sets the stack trace database size, I think here the issue is with windbg truncating the output rather than a stack trace file size